# Deploying Strapi to Azure

Tags: azure, strapi

I want to deploy Strapi to my Azure. Anyone here who has an experience doing such and making it up and running completely? Somehow I couldn't find any detailed instructions how to do that in Azure.. I'm looking for something that is as easy as deploying it to [Heroku](https://blog.strapi.io/deploying-a-strapi-api-on-heroku/) - but it's fine though if it'll require more steps as long as I can make it to work completely.

Answer (score 1):

This is the complete instruction I have also created in the README of the repository.

## Strapi-Azure 3.1.3

This is a working repository of [Strapi 3.1.3](https://github.com/jaybanaticla/strapi-azure) which you can already deploy as an Azure Web App. This requres a paid subscription, minimum of B1 plan (32 USD estimated), so we can enable the 64-bit platform configuration and the Always On feature.

To get started, let us first create and configure our Azure Web App:

**Create an instance:**

- Name: The name of your choice that is still available
- Publish: Code
- Runtime staci: Node 12 LTS
- Operating System: Windows
- Region: select near you
  [image: Create Instance]
- Sku and Size: select B1 (minimum)
  [image: Sku and Size]

**Configure the Environment variables:**

- Add the following key-value pairs:
  [image: Environment variables]
- For the **HOST** make a ping to your *.azurewebsites.net*  instance and get the IP
  [image: Ping]

**Configure the Platform Settings**

- In the *General Settings* tab (beside the *Application Settings*), change the Platform from 32 Bit to 64 Bit
  [image: Platform config]
- To confirm if you are indeed now on 64 Bit mode, go to Console and run **node -p "process.arch"**
  [image: 64bit]

**Install yarn:**
Go again to Console and run: **npm install -g yarn**
[image: Yarn]

**Deploy from your github account a copy of *strapi-azure* repo**

- In the Deployment Center tab, connect your GitHub account and browse your copy of **strapi-azure**
  [image: Wizard1]
- Select **App Service build service** as your build provider
  [image: Wizard2]
- Select repository and branch
  [image: Wizard3]
- **Deploy!**
  [image: Successfully deployed]

**Build your Admin UI using Kudu service**

- Go to Advance Tools -> Go -> expand Debug console from the toolbar -> CMD
- Inside the wwwroot directory (site/wwwroot/), execute **yarn build**

[image: Excute yarn build]

[image: Admin UI built]

**See it in action**

[image: Production live mode]

Answer (score 0):

It should not be any different than installing Strapi on any VM (Azure, AWS, GCP or even local VM).

Quick start guide should help you setup things and run Strapi server --> https://strapi.io/documentation/3.x.x/getting-started/quick-start.html

Primarily: Install nodejs, npm and strapi (via npm). Execute `strapi new cms --quickstart` and you should be good to go (with default configuration).

Comment: Is it possible to use Git repos? Why should we create a new instance of strapi with "strapi new"?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have it within a GIT repository, I may have some useful insights.

When I set mine up, I created an app service hosted on windows - for some reason I found the Linux ones very unstable.  I then used the Deployment Center to then setup the connection between my repository hosted on Azure Devops onto my App Service.  When it deploys IISNode will automatically be setup with an appropriate web.config file for getting a NodeJS server up and running.

You may need to ensure you are running in production (assuming this is what you want), you can set this up by going to the App Service - Configuration - Application Settings (tab) - set up new variable called

```
"NODE_ENV" and set this "PRODUCTION".
```

I also found it useful to set

```
"WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION" and specify the version - in my case it was "10.15.2".
```

For the database I used a ComosDB with the Mongo API, this was hosted on azure and it worked OK - the main problem I found was that I was getting charged a lot for the usage of it, not quite sure at this stage how to get around it.

One thing that did catch me out was setting the "port" variable within the `config/environments/production/server.json` - I was hard coding a port which doesn't work within IISNode - this needs to be set to something like

```
"host": "your.domain.com"
"port": "${process.env.PORT || 1280}"
```

You will also need to setup your database settings in `config/environments/production/database.json` file.

Happy to work through any further points, let me know